# How to fix a mapping of two dimensional array in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, multidimensional-array

I am using angular. Below are typescript and html codes. In typescript code, line  `this.selectedPartyCandidate = this.mappedSenateCandidates.map(_ => 0); //has issues` has error in it. But its working fine with single dimensional array : `this.selectedPartyArray = this.parties.map(_ => 0); //working`. How can i fix this multidimensional array issue?

Error: Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type 'number[][]'.
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'number[]'.

.ts file

```
 interface Candidate {
      id?: Number,
      name: string,
      party: string,
      preferences: Array<Number>
    }
    interface Party {
      party: String,
      preferences: Array<Number>
    }
    
    interface SenateCandidate {
      id: Number,
      attributes: senateCandidateAttributes
    }
    
    interface senateCandidateAttributes {
     
      updatedAt: String
    }
    
    interface mappedSentateCandidate {
      party: String
      candidates: Array<String>
    }
     
    
        constructor() {
            this.selectedPartyArray = this.parties.map(_ => 0); //working
            this.selectedPartyCandidate = this.mappedSenateCandidates.map(_ => 0); //has issues
          }
        
          selectedPartyArray: number[] = [];
          selectedPartyCandidate: number[][] = [];
```

.html file

```
<div *ngFor="let party of parties; index as index">
  <div class="column">
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill" style="max-width: 50px">
      <mat-label></mat-label>
      <mat-select (selectionChange)="preferenceChange($event, party)"  [(ngModel)]="selectedPartyArray[index]" name="preference">
        <mat-option
        *ngFor="let preference of party.preferences" 
        [value]="preference"
        >
        {{preference}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column">
    {{ party.party }}
  </div>
</div>

<p>
  <!-- Submit button -->
  <button mat-raised-button (click)="submit()">Submit</button>
</p>
```

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <div *ngFor="let mappedSenateCandidate of mappedSenateCandidates; index as index">
    <!-- <div class="column" *ngFor="let i = 1; i <= mappedSenateCandidate.length; i++">
      {{`${mappedSenateCandidate}_${i}`}}
    </div> -->
    <div>
      <div><b>{{mappedSenateCandidate.party}}</b></div>
      <div class="inner-flex-container" *ngFor="let candidate of mappedSenateCandidate.candidates; index as index1">
        <mat-form-field appearance="fill" style="max-width: 50px">
          <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedPartyCandidate[index][index1]" name="preference">
            <mat-option
              *ngFor="let preference of senateCandidatePrefereneList"
              [value]="preference"
              >{{ preference }}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
        {{candidate}}
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `has error in it.` What does the error say?

Comment: Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type 'number[][]'.
  Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'number[]'.

Comment: mappedSenateCandidates: Array<mappedSentateCandidate> = []

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.selectedPartyCandidate = this.mappedSenateCandidates.map(_ => 0);
```

`this.mappedSenateCandidates.map(_ => 0)` will create an array of numbers, but `this.selectedPartyCandidate` expects an array of arrays, so you can't assign an array of numbers to it. If you want to assign an array of empty arrays, do this:

```
this.selectedPartyCandidate = this.mappedSenateCandidates.map(_ => []);
```

If you want the sub arrays to have a single 0 in it, then do this:

```
this.selectedPartyCandidate = this.mappedSenateCandidates.map(_ => [0]);
```

If you want the sub arrays to have as many 0's as the original subarray has elements, then do this:

```
this.selectedPartyCandidate = this.mappedSenateCandidates.map(
  subArray => subArray.map(_ => 0)
);
```

---

Alternatively, if you do want a single-dimensional array of numbers, then change the type on this.selectedPartyCandidate:

```
selectedPartyCandidate: number[] = [];
```

Comment: Thanks. In your subArray solution. I am doing like this :
 this.selectedPartyCandidate = this.mappedSenateCandidates.map(
      this.mappedSenateCandidates.candidate => this.mappedSenateCandidate.candidate.map(_ => 0)
    );
but its giving errors.